# Web app HTML parameter passing

Tags: php, javascript, html, web-applications, parameter-passing

I have a web app. I am accessing the web app using the link ...:8080/EPQ/. Web app has only one HTML file. I have the following code in HTML.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id ="id" >
```

I want to pass value for this id through the URL ...:8080/EPQ/. Let me know how to do that.

Comment: URL is of the form http://someip:8080/EPQ/

Comment: if the source html is yours, then you can consider using php to pass in values. url.com?variable=value

Comment: @lukeocom I tried query string like someip:8080/EPQ/?id=1000. The value is not getting passed. HTML is mine only. I can modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your file to have a .php extension instead of .html, then you can use a script to check if a value has been added to the url. Your server must have php installed for this to work of course.

An example would look something like this in your php file.

```
<?php
    //check if var is in URL and store it in $yourVar otherwise store the string 'blank text'
    if ($_GET) {
        $yourVar = $_GET['hidden-val'];
    } else {$yourVar = 'blank text';
    }   
?>
```

your url would look something like this

http://www.yourdomain.com/yourfile.php?hidden-val=somevalue

or if the file is index.php you can use

http://www.yourdomain.com/?hidden-val=somevalue

An alternative solution is to use a javascript/jquery approach, which would look something like..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var yourVar = window.location.search.substring(1);
    alert('you passed in ' + yourVar);
}
```

this thread may be of help also.. [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)